# Building a custom langchain agent

Tags: openai-api, langchain

We are trying to build a custom agent (document processor) with langchain. This agent would enable the user to upload a file and do some process and move the file through different stages based on the user interaction.

langchain documentation refers a example of SalesGPT which matches our requirements, however our code will be run behind an API and the example doesn't work as expected. The sales-agent will be reset every time a request comes and it doesn't go into the loop to get the user requirements[image]. Any guidance or help on this would be extremely helpful.

https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/use_cases/agents/sales_agent_with_context.html

Comment: You can either use langchain's JS API to run your agent on the front end or use just the chain at the backend and keep the memory related functionality like chat history in the front end.